# filepicker.io : merging accounts or cloning files and urls from one to another

Tags: javascript, migration, filepicker.io

I have a question about options and/or approaches for merging/cloning the files of two different filepicker.io accounts.

In an early version of my app, users uploaded some files through an old filepicker account. We switched accounts but failed to migrate the old files to the new accounts at that time. Now I have a mix of filepicker file urls... some point to the old account and S3 instance (that wasn't using security) and some point to the new account to which the files have been uploaded only to filepicker.

Is it possible to merge the two or programmatically determine which account own a given filepicker url? Or even to export all the file urls of one account?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can programmatically determine which account own filepicker file, if you have different containers names in your s3 accounts.

For example you have container_1 on old account and container_2 on new account.

You can make GET requests to https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/File_handle/metadata and you'll receive json with key container.

Comment: This exact thing won't work for me, but I think the spirit of it will. In one of my accounts filepicker stores the files themselves (I believe to S3) but not to my S3. On the other account I am storing them into my own S3.... so I'm guessing I can still use this approach albeit slightly modified.

Answer (score 0):

I received this back from their support team:

> I have an update about your issue. Unfortunately there is no way to
>   merge the files that have been uploaded using two different apps. The
>   only solution to your problem is to manually upload the files once
>   again from one application to another.

I posit this is also a solution:

1. Go into account I would like to merge Go to assets tab Hit Load More until all files are shown
2. Use something like the following to to scrape all URLs that belong to this account

---

```
$(".filelink a").each(function(){
  console.table(
     [this.href,$(this).text()]
  )
})
```

3. Use storeUrl to pick the files from those urls and store them into the newer Filepicker account saving the newly returned Filepicker url alongside the old url
4. do a search andreplace through my application... replace every instance of the old filepicker URL with the new filepicker url